# Freebsd (Freenas 8) and robocopy gives Error 5 Time-Stamping Destination File WHy?

Tags: freebsd, freenas, robocopy

I have a NAS running FreeBSD/FreeNas 8.0.4  When I copy files from a windows system to it via SMB/CIFS normally (explorer/copy) it all goes fine.  User can create/delete/update files

When i attempt the same thing with Robocopy. I get either of 2 errors, depending on command.

```
robocopy .\ \\freenas\temp *.* /FFT
2011/06/15 21:17:58 ERROR 5 (0x00000005) Time-Stamping Destination File \\freenas\temp\test.txt
Access is denied.

robocopy .\ \\freenas\temp *.* /COPY:DA
2011/06/15 21:18:08 ERROR 5 (0x00000005) Changing File Attributes \\freenas\temp\
Access is denied.
```

From the default config, I've set the following in smb.conf

```
[share]
map archive = yes

[global]
dos filetimes = yes
```

Any other clues?

Comment: Here is the closest solution I've found. A upgrade to ZFS v28  [freenas forum](http://forums.freenas.org/showthread.php?1731-CIFS-quot-The-permissions-on-***-are-incorrectly-ordered)  Which I'd have to wait to official get into the Freenas release cycle to verify

Comment: For what it's worth, I have the same issue on a CIFS share on FreeNAS 9.1.1. Permissions are rwxrwx--- and my user is member of the group.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `/COPY:DT` to only copy data and timestamp info, not file attributes. You should probably keep using the `/FFT` switch too.

Comment: Still getting timestamp error.  I've googled around and it just looks like some samba v timestamp issue??? But it's really hard to pinpoint exactly... Other say just use xcopy (which does work)

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem copying from a Windows Server 2008 R2 machine to a Windows Server 2003 domain controller through an RDP client network share (e.g. `\\tsclient\D`).

Using an older version of robocopy from the Windows Server 2003 Resource Kit (XP010) worked fine.

Comment: How do you convert a copy of the older robocopy version?

Answer (score 0):

Try copying over first in restartable mode `/Z`, then backup mode if that failes `/B`, so add the parameter `/ZB` and let us know what happens.  It [might](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/robocopy-error-error-5-copying-ntfs-security-destination-directory-t2852628.html) solve your issue, but no guarantees.  I would also be mighty sure you have your permissions and everything kosher.

Comment: Unfortunately I still get the changing file attributes error with both /Z and /ZB and /B.